# How to implement a Left Outer Join following Core Data Schema?

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using Core Data to implement my ios local db. On it I have a temp entity and a permanent entity.

Is it possible to implement the left outer join concept on these two entities following the Core Data schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data uses an entity relationship model for managing your data and has one of multiple persistence options that happens to be SQLite.

Rather than thinking of how you would solve a problem in SQL, think about how you would solve the problem using your data model. Then, if you have a question about how to use Core Data related to that, ask it here.

Short version: what are you trying to accomplish?